# Fluent nHibernate - Mapping a polymorphic property to a single column in the table

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have something like the classes below, I'd like to map `Foo` to a single table with two columns, `Id` and `State` with values like `1, "BigState"` and `2, "LittleState"` but I'm really struggling to find examples of maps for this.

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public abstract class State
{
}

public class BigState : State
{
}

public class LittleState : State
{
}
```

Comment: Are you using AutoMappingConfiguration?

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I believe so, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html

You are interested in table per class hierarchy strategy. Your second column would be discriminator column. When you are using FluentNhibernate you can derive from DefaultAutomappingConfiguration and override methods `AbstractClassIsLayerSupertype`, `IsDiscriminated`, `GetDiscriminatorColumn`. You also need to implement `IClassConvention` and `ISubclassConvention` to provide class name as discriminator value, something like that.

```
public class SubclassConvention : ISubclassConvention
{
    public void Apply(ISubclassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.DiscriminatorValue(instance.EntityType.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the swift answer, but won't this result in a table for `Foo` and a table for `State`?

Comment: It can be very complicated, I think in this case you have to implement your own column type and save State like serialized json maybe. But why you can't use two tables for that?

Comment: We would rather have had a single table to represent `Foo`, without needing a separate table just to store the `State` of a `Foo`.  Don't worry too much about this though, I think we're going to go down a two table route and make `State` more meaningful.  Thank you :D